# Appending images to Jquery UI Container

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am having a problem appending images to a Jquery UI container. The problem is that when I append an image it places it below where the first image was placed. Regardless of if I then move that image before I add my next one, when I add the next image it appends it to the bottom of the previously appended image. This continues until the image is appended outside of the view of the container and the image is unusable. I have tried using CSS to define an absolute and relative position to the appending images as well but this prevents the ability for these images to be draggable. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank You!

```
$('#2top').live('click',function(){
   var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
   var newBox = "<div id='" + randomNumber + "' class='draggable ui-widget-content'><img src='pictures/2-chair-tableRounded.png' height='35' width='35'></div>"; 

   $('#containment-wrapper').append(newBox);

    var id = '#' + randomNumber;

   $(id).draggable({
        containment: "#containment-wrapper", scroll: false,
        grid: [5,5]

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're are looking for jQuery's `.prepend()`, instead of `.append()`. `.prepend()` will always insert the content at the beginning of the container.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That allows me access to all images that I add to the container but that brings up a new problem. If using prepend, All the images that I have already added to the container are forced down from the positions that I set them at when I 'prepend' a new image.

Comment: So, where exactly do you want the news images to be inserted?

Comment: I would like to be able to specify a location on the canvas to place a new image when I add one, all while not affecting the current layout that is being created by the user. I believe this is a CSS issue but when I try to use positioning, it disables Jquery UI's ability to make the image draggable.

Comment: Maybe you could try to do exactly like draggable does: use `position:relative` + `top` and `left` to set the position of the images. You'll probably have to do that on draggable's `create` event ([docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-create)), or your changes might be overriden by jQueryUI.